# How to insert data to database using nodejs , postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Here's my connection

```
const client = new Client({
    user: 'ozan',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'blogpage',
    password: 'test',
    port: 5432,
});
client.connect();

client.query('SELECT * from persons', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
    client.end()
});`
```

And here is my post route

```
routes.post('/signup',(req, res)=> {


    const data = {username: req.body.usernamebody, email: req.body.emailbody, password: req.body.passwordbody};


    client.query('INSERT INTO persons(username,password,email) values($1, $2,$3)',
        [data.username, data.password, data.email]);


    });
```

All of code's in same page (just learning)

Where is my mistake's  i read the all of document's and still can't insert data... thanks for the time

Comment: Are you getting any error messages...? "can't insert data" is a useless problem description [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with NodeJS asynchronous behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692946/dealing-with-nodejs-asynchronous-behavior)

Comment: no, i tried error handling and developer tools and  got nothing.When i click the submit button its loading and it times out.

Comment: What postgres client are you using?  What version of Node?  Also, it times out because you're never ending the response (e.g. res.end(); res.send())

Comment: Postgres version is 10.3. Node version 9.9.0. Now i am thinking about compatibility between node and postgre

Comment: No, which Postgres client are you using, and version?  The npm module?

Comment: pgAdmin4 v2.1  and npm module is 'pg' @7.4.1